# Calculated textbox to dynamic table record

Tags: ms-access, logging, vba

I am trying to get a calculated textbox' value to copy to a table with a Date()-mark.

I have several textboxes, with similar code to count in queries (This is "Text39" textbox):

```
=DCount("*";"[QRY_ALLE_faktura&kreditnota_forfald]")
```

This is counting all open invoices of today and returning ex. "550" as value.

I want to have a button to copy all the values from the 5 textboxes to a table into the specific columns.
Each time the button is clicked, it should timestamp it with Date() (Dynamic rows?)

I've read all questions about the topic in here, none which seem to fit my problem. I've also spend a few full days of googling this, but have come out with no results.

How do i get the value from Text39 textbox copied to Table "Test", column "Depot" while it already made the new row and in column "Date" inserted today's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnClick event of the button, run code similar to this:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "Insert Into Test ([TimeStamp], [Depot], [NextField], [AnotherField]) Values (Date()," & Me!Text39.Value & "," & Me!Text40.Value & "," & Me!Text41.Value & ")"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

But, do yourself a favour an rename the textboxes to something meaningful like `txtDepot`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gustav!
However, when i click the button, it returns "Run-time error '2465', as i cannot find the field "Text39" that's being referred to."

Comment: I renamed it to "txtDepot" as suggested (Thanks for that!) and it is now copying the data!!!! 

Thank you so much, man, this is exactly what i've been looking for! Have a great day, you just made mine a whole lot better!